# digital image processing

Tags: c, image-processing

I am really new to digital image processing and is fixed with the below mentioned problem:-
I need to write a C program which will load a ppm image file and do line detection with convolution kernels. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I agree. You need to read up some references on image processing, maybe pick up a basic image processing textbook. Once you have attempted to solve this problem, if you face any issues in the implementation, then it would be more appropriate to post a question here.

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for: http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Daniel Not necessarily better, I think it's fit for both. This isn't the first image-processing programming question on this website. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing

Answer (score 8):

1. First off, you need open the file with `fopen(..)`
2. Second you need to design an array or data structure store the image.
3. Then you need to design a mask for each type of angle
4. Add a border depending on the size of the mask, and convolve the mask with the image
5. save unto a file

Might find this link helpful
http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/edge.html

To Implement the masks in the links you're refering to, take this code and change GX and GY to
a) and b)

`/* 3x3 GX Sobel mask.  Ref: www.cee.hw.ac.uk/hipr/html/sobel.html */`

`GX[0][0] = -1; GX[0][1] = 2; GX[0][2] = -1;`

`GX[1][0] = -1; GX[1][1] = 2; GX[1][2] = -1;`

`GX[2][0] = -1; GX[2][1] = 2; GX[2][2] = -1;`

`/* 3x3 GY Sobel mask.  Ref: www.cee.hw.ac.uk/hipr/html/sobel.html */`

`GY[0][0] =  -1; GY[0][1] =  -1; GY[0][2] =  -1;`

`GY[1][0] =  2; GY[1][1] =  2; GY[1][2] =  2;`

`GY[2][0] = -1; GY[2][1] = -1; GY[2][2] = -1;`

Same for c) and d)

Other than creating from scratch you could also use the open source **openCV**
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html
There are online documentation and textbooks on how to use it too
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596516134](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)

Comment: Nice guidance. Not too much, just the right amount to get a person started

Comment: Can anybody suggest any good book or pointer for image processing...especially line detection.

Comment: I used, for class, and liked rafael's Concept->
http://www.amazon.com/dp/013168728X, and Matlab tutorial -> http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Image-Processing-Using-MATLAB/dp/0982085400/ref=pd_sim_b_1     I'd recommend looking at coursera.com computer vision courses for more material

Comment: @echad I want in C not in matlab.

Comment: @user2481422 Easy way to go about it is openCV API. They have textbooks for that too. Here's a document for edge detection on openCV
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

Comment: @echad I want line detection not edge detection

Comment: @user2481422 Look. Edge detection is a mathematical method, can be applied for detecting points or lines. In the previous link example they do use a line detector for mask. Here are more example of line masks http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/linedet.htm

Comment: @echad this is the link that I was referring to but do you know how to implement it?

Comment: @user2481422 edited my answer, don't forget to accept answer if I finished answering your question

Comment: @echad this might seems silly for you but will this work for ppm image files or only for gray scale image files? As, I want for color ppm image files

Comment: @user2481422 It should. Try changing the include part of the code to < > instead of ( ). Like
#include <alloc.h>

PS I'm sure with enough search ull find answers to questions like this on stackoverflow. These comments sections aren't meant for extended discussions. Trying writing from scratch and imitating the algorithms of the code.